# Agfa SnapScan e50 scanner doesn't work with Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, mac, scanner

We have just upgraded from 10.5 to 10.6 and now our Agfa e50 scanner no longer works.

We have attempted to download and install the SnapScan software from the Agfa website, but before the installation it gives a fatal error, claiming to require monitor calibration. After we have run the calibration tool in Sys Prefs, it still doesn't work.

It's quite an old scanner but obviously still works perfectly, so we'd prefer to have it working again.

Has anyone managed to fix this or is there some other software we could be using instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a post](http://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-14288245-drivers-scanner-agfa-sous-mac-os-10-6) online with the very same concern when 10.6 came out. Attempts to contact Agfa were without resolution. Instead, two solutions emerged from that thread:

TWAIN SANE drivers and a SANE front-end. There's an [OS X TWAIN SANE](http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/) page that has 5 binary packages that you would need. [ScanAgain](http://homepage.mac.com/dtlinker/ScanAgain/) is SANE front-end. Free.

[image: ScanAgain]

[VueScan](http://www.hamrick.com/), which is a self-contained program with drivers for over 1200 scanners, and works for 10.6. $39.95 with free trial.

[image: VueScan]

Comment: Glad I could help.